# Error extending Tensorflow object detection tutorial to multiple classes

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection-api

I'm trying to extend [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/b817230217e36af83015f8fc101e7e24cd2f5cf7/research/object_detection/colab_tutorials/eager_few_shot_od_training_tf2_colab.ipynb) example from the `tensorflow/models/research/object_detection` project to support multiple classes using a custom dataset but I'm hitting an error that I don't understand. I'm a total amateur with machine learning concepts, I'm just trying to get a model trained so that I can do object detection in an application I'm developing.

The error is:

```
ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable: ['WeightSharedConvolutionalBoxPredictor/WeightSharedConvolutionalBoxHead/BoxPredictor/kernel:0', 'WeightSharedConvolutionalBoxPredictor/WeightSharedConvolutionalBoxHead/BoxPredictor/bias:0', 'WeightSharedConvolutionalBoxPredictor/WeightSharedConvolutionalClassHead/ClassPredictor/kernel:0', 'WeightSharedConvolutionalBoxPredictor/WeightSharedConvolutionalClassHead/ClassPredictor/bias:0'].
```

A fully working Google Colab notebook showing the issue is [here](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1Z0usFgYYp8ngw3fG9Nut257es826ot5A?usp=sharing). You should be able to make a copy of the notebook and then click `Runtime -> Run All` to reproduce the issue.

The changes I've made to the original notebook (annotated with `[MITCH]` in my notebook) are:

- Parse labels from a labelmap file rather than hard-code them.
- Derive the number of classes from the parsed labelmap rather than hard-code.
- Use custom dataset from google drive (labeled with `labelImg`).
- Fix other hard-coded assumptions about the number of classes.

I'm guessing I just missed something else hard-coded but I can't spot it... Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got an [answer on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/MLQuestions/comments/hx7rtl/could_use_some_help_extending_the_tensorflow/fz54ui5?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x). I was simply missing a call to `model.predict()`... I must have just fat-fingered it. `/facepalm`